# What specific criteria are required to create a house for a villager in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Creating_a_village#Simple) isn't very clear on what constitutes a house. Simply, it says that a villager would consider a bed a house.

Does this mean that as long as there's an unobstructed bed, it won't matter what the building looks like?

Answer (score 1):

Yup! Many villager farms are simple because large houses are not needed. Nearby beds should work (Though only one villager can use one bed. Multiple villagers can not use the same one bed.)

Answer (score 0):

They need a bed basically, but if you are doing a farm, it's better that they also have work stations, and if you are making you own vilage, use doors so they run there in raids and at night.